# How many java processes are started when executing maven commands within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jvm

When we open a eclipse which runs in its own jvm and we can set memory for jvm in eclipse.inf file.

When we open the eclipse and run any maven commands from maven for example

```
mvn jetty:run
```

this runs on how many jvms..?

Is that the one java for maven command to execute and other for running jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Maven is started in an own Java process (JVM if you will) and the Maven Jetty plugin is starting Jetty in an own Java process.

That the Jetty plugin uses an own JVM environment, which means it runs in an own process, can be read implicitly from here: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html. There it says that if you provide any system properties, they will not override the command line properties, which is the hint.

> systemProperties: System properties to set before execution. Note that these properties will NOT override System properties that have been set on the command line or by the JVM.